# Excel default text color weirdness

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

How does Excel choose which color a newly added text will be? I makes no sense to me, look...

To be sure there isn't any invisible formatting on the cells, start with a fresh sheet and add some values:

[image: screenshot]

Then make them gray, only the actual values:

[image: screenshot]

Now try to add a new, black, value:

[image: screenshot]

So, in the columns with three values, I have to keep a distance of at least three cells to get a black value. But in the columns with just two or a single value I don't have to keep any distance at all? Or is the logic completely different and I just don't see it?

I tried clearing formats, clearing everything, creating new columns and re-typing the data into them, I can't get consistent behavior.

Comment: Is this effect true for you on any new worksheet?  Try a full Repair of Office (Programs and Features, select Office and Change).  If that fails, try Excel in a different Windows User Name.

Comment: @John I have tested it also. It is the same as the OP. using 365.

Comment: I am using Office 365 here and my new cells are always black. Vanilla setup and formatting.

Comment: Office 2019 : Always black. Try maybe to disable all add-ons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from [here](https://www.excelhow.net/how-to-stop-autofill-color-for-extend-cells-in-excel.html) and [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1988-excel-stop-auto-fill-color.html). It is a normal behavior of Excel not bug as stated [here](https://www.excelhow.net/how-to-stop-autofill-color-for-extend-cells-in-excel.html#menu-item-1963:%7E:text=We%20may%20notice%20that%20if%20we,filled%20with%20background%20color%20as%20well.):

> We may notice that if we enter some cells with background color continuously, when you enter a value in the next adjacent cell, the cell is filled with background color as well.

To stop it, go to File -> Options. In the Advanced section, uncheck "Enable data range formats and formulas". Click OK.

[image: IMG:]

When you go back to your worksheet, the auto fil color format will not extend to the other cells.

**With the option checked**

[image: IMG:]

**With the option unchecked**

[image: IMG:]